# msvcr100d.dll!_heap_alloc_base(unsigned int size=80) Line 55 fails and throws

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

It throws on code alike:

```
template<class T>
T* new_p(){
    T* result =  (T*) operator new (sizeof(T)); // HERE
    memset(result, 0, sizeof(T));
    result = new (result) T();
    return result;
}
```

[image]

[image]

So new does not work in VS2010 sometimes of I do something wrong?

Comment: if new did not work in VS2010 when you had available memory, c++ programs would be difficult to write indeed

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, when you have heap assert errors like this, it means that you screwed something up *earlier*. It's probably not the current `malloc`/`new` you're executing that's the problem.

Perhaps you called `free` / `delete` twice for the same allocation, or you overran a heap-allocated buffer. These are often difficult to track down, unfortunately.

- [Debugging heap corruption in Visual Studio](https://www.google.com/search?q=debugging%20heap%20corruption%20visual%20studio)

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen new used like that. Maybe I'm not understanding what you are trying to do with that code, but this is how I would have thought it should be.

```
template<class T>
T* new_p(){
    T* result =  new T();
    memset(result, 0, sizeof(T)); //BTW, I doubt this will do good things
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @BTW: related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500962/how-can-one-branch-of-class-tree-have-all-its-zero-initialized-members-be-rubbis

Comment: Point was to initialize class after setting memory values under it to `0`

Comment: Usually you let the constructor of the class handle its initialization. Here you are blanket setting everything to zero, including private members. This could have undesirable effects.

Comment: Yet than I called constructor on top of that cleaned memory=)

Comment: But new creates a new memory block. There is a memory leak here.

Comment: @metalhead well he uses placement new on the second call which uses the old allocated memory. While this is not the idiomatic way to do things i suppose, it seems valid

Comment: but yes the memset is unnecessary unless the constructor does not do the work it should do

Comment: I stand corrected. I've never seen the placement new before. Thanks @AK4749