# VC++ MFC Application on Windows 10 - An invalid handle was specified

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, windows-10

I created a new C++ MFC MDI Application in Visual Studio.

**FIRST PROBLEM** - 
The exception `An invalid handle was specified` is thrown when launching it in Debug/Release (x86 only).

Here is my config. :

- Visual Studio Pro 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
- Windows 10 Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.292)
- .NET Framework Version 4.7.03190
- Visual C++ Redistributable installed (2005, 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015)

Pressing "Break" : Without Microsoft Symbol Servers, it shows something went wrong in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll`. With Microsoft Symbol Servers, it just shows "Source Not Available".

Pressing "Continue" one or two times : Launches the application, which can be used normally.

When exiting the app by clicking on the dialog "X" button, an `Access violation reading location` is also thrown in ntdll.dll. This exception is thrown in (x86) AND (x64).

I tested it on 3 others PCs running Windows 10 (older version) and the same thing happens. I tested it on 2 PCs running Windows 7 and there is no problem.

***EDIT -***
Please see the two following screenshots for the call stack after each of these exceptions are thrown.

[Callstack for Invalid Handle Exception when launching the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2X1J.jpg)

[Callstack for Access Violation Exception when exiting the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLkLC.jpg)

**SECOND PROBLEM** - The values of initialized variables are **randomly** wrong.

For example, I have seen this in a base class constructor :

```
variable = 0; // int
```

The debugger shows me that `variable` value is `52685`. Not sure if it is a coincidence but the ID of the VC++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3 is 52685 (see URL param).

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3 / id=52685](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685)

The output of `variable` in the console shows the correct value (0).

I would appreciate to have some help to resolve this issue as it makes debugging really hard. The only thing I am sure is that it is related to Windows 10.

***EDIT -***
Please see the two following screenshots of variables values while debugging. In the first one, you can see that all "int" variables have the value -842150451 (which should be 0 instead, right?). These variables are declared in the private section of a class. The second screenshot shows the default constructor of this class. One of these "int" (image_bpp) shows the value 52685 instead of the assigned 0. If I switch the initialization of image_bpp and image_pixel_color, then it is the image_pixel_color that shows the wrong value.

[Declared variables values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv0KS.jpg)

[Initialized variables values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIhNd.jpg)

Looks like I am not the first one with this issue. I forgot to mention that I am using a simple inheritance (instanciating a derived class, then the constructor of the base class is called and this is where I put my breakpoint).

See this link for reference : [Compiler bug with derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500962/how-can-one-branch-of-class-tree-have-all-its-zero-initialized-members-be-rubbis)

Comment: You say this is a new empty application. Is it MFC dialog based application? or is it SDI, MDI etc.?

Comment: It is a MDI application. After selecting MFC, the wizard is shown and I let the default settings. I will try again tomorrow to see if it happens with all types of MFC apps.

Comment: Try "Use MFC in a static library" in the "Use of MFC" setting in the first wizard page.

Comment: Tried MFC (SDI, MDI, Dialog Based) static and dynamic - same problem.
Also tried Win32 Application (Windows application) - same problem.

The only application that does not throw these exceptions is a Console App.

Comment: I have the exact Windows 10 Version, using VS 2017 community version, can't duplicate the error. Maybe you have a weird anti-virus program installed on some systems? Otherwise upload a small project to some website so we can see.

Comment: I do have an antivirus installed (Norton Symantec). I disabled it along with the firewall but still having the issue. 

The antivirus is also installed on some Windows 7 computers which are not experiencing the problem. Transfering the project sources to a Windows 7 PC and running the app on the same version of Visual Studio cause no issue. I could probably try a VS 2017 trial version.

Comment: Does the "initialized variables are wrong" - problem occur in both debug and release builds? In release builds that is expected to happen, since the variable may e.g. be placed in a CPU register that is then reused for something else.
If it only happens in debug code, you can further disable optimizations in release mode to see if it gets fixed.

Comment: Please see the two screenshots of variables values while debugging. In the first one, you can see that all "int" variables have the value -842150451 (which should be 0 instead, right?). These variables are declared in the private section of a class. The second screenshot shows the default constructor of this class. One of these "int" (image_bpp) shows the value 52685 instead of the assigned 0. If I switch the initialization of image_bpp and image_pixel_color, then it is the image_pixel_color that shows the wrong value.

Comment: @SamiSallinen Only happens while debugging in Visual Studio. The right value is assigned (because a print of the variable displays the correct value). Only the value shown in "Locals" section or by leaving my mouse on a variable are sometimes wrong. Running the build outside of VS looks fine.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I would like to know if you got a "Target Platform Version" set in the project general properties, and which "Platform Toolset" you use. It looks like my default "Target Platform Version" is Windows 8.1 and the "Platform Toolset" is Visual Studio 2015 (v140).

Comment: What does the stack trace window show? In Debug mode you should see the exception and be able to bring up the stack window to see which of your functions is creating the environment for the exception. At that point you should be able to inspect variables.

Comment: @RichardChambers Please see the two screenshots I have uploaded for problem #1. I can't inspect variables since the exception is thrown in a Microsoft DLL (ntdll).

Comment: What I see are screen shots of local variable dumps not the stack trace. My question is where in your code is the call that results in the call into the ntdll with a bad handle. I'm curious if the stack is good or if there is something that is overwriting memory. I'm curious what call is triggering the exception. If everything is good then you should be able to see the complete call stack and see which function within your code is invoking the Microsoft functionality which is reporting the bad handle.

Comment: @RichardChambers You are not opening the right screenshots. I edited my post to divide it in two separate problems in bold, which I originally thought were linked. Please refer to the first problem and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @WernerHenze Someone asked me to show the stack trace. Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: @Vincent-SimonBolduc Did you follow the link and read the page? I am not downvoting for the stack trace but for the images. Why? Read the page, it's all described there.

Comment: The "incorrectly initialized variables" seem to be uninitialized memory. The visual studio debug runtime initializes all allocated memory to the hex byte 0xCD  = 205 decimal. In an int with all bytes 0xcd, you get the value -842150451. (The point of such initialization is to make it easier to detect the use of uninitialized variables.)

Comment: I used *Target platform Windows 10 + highest SDK version + Platform Toolset Visual Studio 2017 (v140)*, but doubtful it makes a difference here.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani You are right. Tried to build with Windows 10 latest SDK, still have the issue. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @WernerHenze I did read the page you linked. However, there seems to be no way to see more details than what is shown on my images.